# CPU fan runs fast with low temperature and low usage

Tags: 19.10, fan, fancontrol

I have Ubuntu 19.10 on an ASUS N750JK laptop, and it makes the CPU fan run fast almost all the time, without any apparent good reason. The battery gets drained quite fast. This is the output of sensors:

```
$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +51.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +51.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +48.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +48.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +50.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +51.0°C  (crit = +103.0°C)

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:     4600 RPM
temp1:        +51.0°C
```

I tried to manually lower the CPU frequency to 2GHz, when the max allowed by hardware is 3.4GHz, but that doesn't help. I also installed `tlp`. What could cause this issue?

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL (http://ubuntu-news.org/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) and thus off-topic unless your question is specific about problems released to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  You should *release-upgrade* asap.  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic   Use a LTS (long-term-support) release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.

Comment: I updated to 19.10, thank you for pointing that out. The fan issue is still there though

Comment: those temps are running hot a quite machine runs closer to 25 C   so I would open up a terminal and run  `top`  update your question with output